# How to compare two formula results?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any way to compare two formulas to get either the result, if they produce the same result, or False?

Example:

```
B8+B9 vs. C4-C2
```

Result:

Compare both formulas, and either show FALSE, if they produce different results, or the value of B8+B9 (let´s say 17), if they produce the same result?

Comment: your current formula will show `FALSE` if they are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

Use IF to produce a different result based a condition.

```
=IF(B8+B9=C4-C2,B8+B9,"FALSE")
```

It evaluates whether `B8+B9=C4-C2` is true or false.  If true, it returns the first result, if false, it returns the second.

Comment: Nice & easy one,, perfect 10 :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Do the Followings:**

**D66** `= (D64+D65)`

**E66**  `=(E64-E65)`

In **F66** write this formula: `=IF(D66=E66, D66, "False")`

**Note,** *adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: Your question edit changed the meaning a little, so I tweaked it back to the original plus your polish.  This answer isn't really what the OP was asking.  They want to compare the result (17) of two different formulas (which aren't necessarily cell contents), not the formula text, which will always be different (otherwise there's no reason to compare).  You're likely to attract downvotes with this one.